# Get possible sequence from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having an Array like,

```
const array = [1,3,4,5,6] // array will have unique values
```

I want to get the possible sequence from that array in optimised way
and sequence length should be greater than 3

Example: I should get `[[3,4,5,6]]`

examples:

`[1,2,3,5,8,9,10]` => output should be `[[1,2,3],[8,9,10]]`

I have tried `Array.every` but not able to figure out when sequence breaks in between.

Comment: `possible sequence` can you elaborate it more ? what should happen if there are multiple sequences ?

Comment: no array will be having unique values

Comment: Are they always sorted ? you still didn't answered what should happen in case there are multiple sequences, i.e `[1,2,3,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16]` what should be output ?

Comment: multiple sequences means like what if an array is like: `[1,3,4,5,6,9,10,11,12,13]`, what should be result then?

Comment: it should return all possible sequences

Comment: So it will return an array of array, not a simple array, correct?

Comment: Updated your question to have array of array in case of one sequence as well

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Did you give a try to a *good old loop* ?

Comment: yes, tried some theory to practice stuff, but ending but loop in loop in loop

Comment: Would you show us ? You might be closer to the solution than you expect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const data = [1,2,3,5,8,9,10];
const result = data.reduce((seq, v, i, a) => {
 if (i && a[i - 1] !== v - 1) {
  seq.push([]);
 }
 seq[seq.length - 1].push(v);
 return seq;
}, [[]]).filter(({length}) => length > 1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

- Have two variable one for final output, second for temporary sequence
- Loop over array and see if the difference between `i+1` and `i` index is `1` if one add it to temp, if not check if the temp is having length greater then `0` and then add the value to final output accordingly

```js
const getSequence = (arr) => {
  let sequence = []
  let temp = []

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ((arr[i+1] - arr[i]) === 1) {
      temp.push(arr[i])
    } else {
      if (temp.length) {
        sequence.push([...temp,arr[i]])
        temp = []
      }
    }
  }
  if(temp.length) sequence.push(temp)
  return sequence
}

console.log(getSequence([1, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
console.log(getSequence([1,2,3,5,8,9,10]))
console.log(getSequence([1,2,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,78,97,98,99]))
```

Answer (score 1):

.every(someFunctionThatReturnsTrueOrFalse) returns a boolean and checks whether all elements in the array satisfy a condition or not. You want to consider multiple elements at the same time for a very specific purpose. I guess you'd have to write a custom function for this.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
  var array1 = [bunch of values];
   var i;
   var j;
   var optimizedArr1 = [array1[0]];
   var optimizedArr2 = [];
   for(j = 0; j < array1.length-1; j = i){
     optimizedArr2.push(array1[j]);

     for(i = j; i < array1.length; i++){
      if(array1[i+1]-array1[i] != 1){
        if(optimizedArr1.length < optimizedArr2.length)
        {
          optimizedArr1 = optimizedArr2;
        }
          optimizedArr2 = [];
          i++;
          break;

      } else {
         optimizedArr2.push(array1[i+1])
      }
     }
    }
   return optimizedArr2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data =[-1,0,1,3,4,5,6,8,9,13,14];


function getSequence(dataArray){
  let results = [];
  let temp = [];
  temp.push(data[0])
  console.log(temp)
  for(let i= 0; i < data.length -1; i++){
    if (Math.abs((data[i+1] - data[i])) == 1){
       temp.push(data[i + 1])
    }
    else{
      if(temp.length >= 2){
        results.push(temp)
      }
      temp = []
      temp.push(data[i + 1])
    }

  }

   if (temp.length >= 2){
      results.push(temp)
    }

  return results;
}
console.log(getSequence(data))
```

This should work assuming it's given sorted data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sequence(arr) {
  let ret = [];
  let temp = [];
  let hasNext = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] + 1 === arr[i + 1]) {
      temp.push(arr[i]);
      hasNext = true;
    } else {
      if (hasNext) {
        temp.push(arr[i]);
      }
      if (temp.length > 0) {
        ret.push(temp);
        temp = [];
      }
      hasNext = false;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

console.log(sequence([1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20]));
console.log(sequence([1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]));
```